# "can't write to read-only destination file" with ANT

Tags: ant

Ant build fails with below error about "can't write to read-only destination file". Is this an issue with Windows permissions error or something with Ant?

```
BUILD FAILED
E:\app\jenkins\workspace\CardsAdmin\Test-Build2\ca_module\build.xml:32: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\app\jenkins\workspace\CardsAdmin\Test-Build2\ca_module\caRest\build.xml:116: Failed to copy E:\app\jenkins\workspace\CardsAdmin\Test-Build2\ca_module\caRest\WebContent\WEB-INF\tealeaf-w3c-dev.js to E:\app\jenkins\workspace\CardsAdmin\Test-Build2\ca_module\caRest\WebContent\WEB-INF\web\tealeaf-w3c-dev.js due to can't write to read-only destination file E:\app\jenkins\workspace\CardsAdmin\Test-Build2\ca_module\caRest\WebContent\WEB-INF\web\tealeaf-w3c-dev.js
```

Comment: What's your ANT version? And also please show me the snippet for the copy task in your `build.xml`

Comment: using ANT version 1.8.2      <copy todir="${web.home}/WEB-INF/web">
  <fileset dir="${web.home}/WEB-INF">
    <include name="**/*.*"/>
  </fileset>
  </copy>

Answer (score 3):

Prior to `ANT 1.8.2`, it was able to copy files to read-only destinations. However, after `1.8.2` the behavior has changed.

So, in this case, you can force the [copy](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) task to make it work:

```
<copy force="true" todir="${web.home}/WEB-INF/web"> 
   <fileset dir="${web.home}/WEB-INF"> 
     <include name="*/.*"/> </fileset> 
</copy>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had the problem with this configuration in my pom.xml, which throws that exception (*can't write to read-only destination file*) when i run ***mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean package***:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
          <target>
            <echo force="true" file="${basedir}/src/main/resources/version.properties" message="test.version=${project.version}${line.separator}"/>
            <echo force="true" file="${basedir}/src/main/resources/version.properties" message="test.build=${buildNumber}${line.separator}" append="true"/>
            <echo force="true" file="${basedir}/src/main/resources/version.properties" message="test.timestamp=${timestamp}" append="true"/>
          </target>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The key was to put **force="true"** in each "echo" tag.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates a permissions problem.  You can use the "force" option the other posters mention, but you should consider whether you'll be better off fixing the underlying problem.

For example, I've encountered this error after I've manually moved a file into the build directory for testing, which you might have done with `WEB-INF\tealeaf-w3c-dev.js`.  In this case, the build fails because Ant doesn't have permission to overwrite a file that's owned by me.  The solution here is to remove that file so that the build can write that file and complete normally.